# Timeseries input to an LSTM

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm

I have dataset containing water samples collected from different locations. For example, ABC1 water sample is taken from a river in Arizona and ABC2 is a water sample taken from a river in Boston. They are both rivers, they have the same feature columns(pH, temp, etc...) but they are in different locations so the changes in features are individual to them. So my goal is to create **one river model** because I do not have enough data to create individual models. There are total 11 columns that I want to predict next months values. My dataset looks like this:

```
Date         Sample_Name        pH    temp    etc...

2009-01-01    ABC1              7.2    12
2009-01-02    ABC2              5.5    11
.
.
2009-01-02    ABC1              7.2    10
2009-01-02    ABC2              7.3    10
.
.
2013-06-02    ABC2              6.5    22
2013-06-04    ABC1              6.5    22
.
2015-01-05    ABC1              8.9    13
2015-01-05    ABC4              8.8    13
```

I want to feed every sample and its sequence to an LSTM model. For example; every measurement(row) of ABC1 must be given to a model as a sequence, or a batch.
Is it possible to do this kind of data preparation using TimeseriesGenerator? How can I prepare my data in a way to feed it to the model as I described? Also does it help to sort the dataset with date and sample name(alphabetically)? [I am trying to achieve something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61177311/creating-a-timeseriesgenerator-with-multiple-inputs)

I want to generate data using:

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
n_timesteps = 2
n_features = 10
batch_size = 5
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(df, df, length, sampling_rate = 10, stride = 1, batch_size = batch_size)
```

The simple LSTM model that I want to feed my data in:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from keras.utils import Sequence

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_features, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/TimeseriesGenerator),tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator cannot take a dictionary as the first argument. The 'slice' error is just a manifestation of that fact, as the function tries to use slices of the first argument (dict) and fails. again from the docs:

> Arguments: data: Indexable generator (such as list or Numpy array) containing consecutive data points (timesteps).

so perhaps you want to pass `input_dict['ABC1']` or possibly `input_dict['ABC1'].values`

Comment: I understand this but isn't it possible to pass them all at once? If I apply your suggestion, I have to store 170 models, and my data is definitely not enough if I do that because every sample has 70 rows at max.

Comment: I understood from your question that you wanted to train your models separately

Comment: I am trying to feed in every water source as a sequence or a batch because they behave very similarly given an interval of time.

Comment: then perhaps you should not split them by sample, and feed the original database in as one?

Comment: Sure, but how would I group them? For example lets say a water sample is taken from a river in Arizona and the other one is taken from a river from Boston. They are both rivers, but they are in different locations and have the same feature columns. Their time intervals matter a lot because i am trying to predict the next months feature columns. I believe that to extract a great model I need to feed them as a sequence. It would have taken a very short time if I had enough data, but since a water sample contains like 70 rows, I can't.

Comment: If you can specify how you want your sample to look like, we can help you transform your data to the right format. But we cannot do the 'spec' part for you I am afraid!

Comment: I have updated my question with more clear instructions. I will be happy if you can check it out again.